# htaccess rewrite url hostgator

Tags: html, .htaccess

I've been struggeling to get a .htaccess file to work correctly for a while now. What I basically want is to change the domain from e.g. www.domain.com/products/products.html to www.domain.com/products I've been trying for so long that I've started to consider it being unsupported by my hosting service (hostgator, and they don't know).

This is the code I scrambled together that only gives me the default missing page error.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^test?$ hidden/hidden.html [NC,L]
```

The structure:
 
Folder (hidden) -> Hidden.html
Index.html
.htaccess

I made some progress while my wait, I was able to get 3 links working however not the fourth one. That leaves me more confused the before.

My code currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^staff$ staffmembers/staffmembers.html [L]
RewriteRule ^donate$ idonate/idonate.html [L]
RewriteRule ^private$ hidden/hidden.html [L]
```

The only link that dosn't work is website.com/donate however every other links works fine at this point. Anyone that have a clue of why or a solution of how?

Comment: As long as it's in the `products/` directory on the server, just change `products.html` to `index.html`. The same goes for your other paths (`idonate`, `staffmembers`, etc). The server will automatically attempt to load `index.html` when you navigate to a particular URL with a path such as `domain.com/products`.

Comment: It will forever be beyond me from this point how I did not think of that. It worked amazing. Thanks mate.